# Flask app and JQuery not being loaded properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

UPDATE: Tried everything in the answer below and it hasn't helped.

I've got a Flask app and in the templates I'm running some JQuery. The JQuery pulls in the [Aviary editor](http://developers.aviary.com/)..or it's supposed to, on page load. For some reason the JQuery isn't running in the proper sequence or something, because the editor only works if I add an artificial delay to the JQuery function. For example, this does not work:

> ```
> <script type='text/javascript'>
>     id = "image";
>
>    var featherEditor = new Aviary.Feather({
>        apiKey: 'my_api_key',
>        apiVersion: 3,
>        theme: 'minimum', // Check out our new 'light' and 'dark' themes!
>        tools: 'all',
>        noCloseButton: true,
>        appendTo: 'result-image',
>        onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {
>             //this code was removed for brevity
>        },
>        onError: function(errorObj) {
>            alert(errorObj.message);
>        }
>    });
>        function launchEditor(id) {
>            featherEditor.launch({
>                image: id
>            });
>           return false;
>         }
>     $(document).ready(function() {
>            launchEditor(id);
>     });
> </script>
> ```

But this code below works fine. After the delay runs out, the editor launches:

> ```
> <script type='text/javascript'>
>     id = "image";
>
>    var featherEditor = new Aviary.Feather({
>        apiKey: 'my_api_key',
>        apiVersion: 3,
>        theme: 'minimum', // Check out our new 'light' and 'dark' themes!
>        tools: 'all',
>        noCloseButton: true,
>        appendTo: 'result-image',
>        onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {
>             //this code was removed for brevity
>        },
>        onError: function(errorObj) {
>            alert(errorObj.message);
>        }
>    });
>        function launchEditor(id) {
>            featherEditor.launch({
>                image: id
>            });
>           return false;
>         }
>   $(document).ready(function() {
>             setTimeout(
>                            function() 
>                            { 
>                                     launchEditor(id);
>                            }, 3500);
>
>    });
> </script>
> ```

I tried using (window).load() instead, moving the javascript from the header to the footer and a bunch of other things. The only thing that got the editor to load properly was adding a delay of a few seconds to the function call.

Now, while this was fine for testing, this isn't very conducive to a happy user experience. I'd like to figure out why the function isn't working until a few seconds after the page finishes loading.

Any advice is appreciated! Thank you

Comment: @Bibhas these are in a Flask application using Jinja2 templates. I didn't want to leave any detail out in case Jinja2 does anything funny during render or something like that

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your image isn't loaded yet, and that's why it won't work immediately on page load. Try checking if the image is loaded before you open the editor, maybe with something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(id).one('load', function () {
        launchEditor($(this).attr('id'));
    }).each(function () {
        if (this.complete) $(this).load();
    });
});
```

*Image loaded check borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached)*

Comment: Hmm, this never fires even though I know the image is loaded in the DOM, I can see it in Firebug and if I call launchEditor(id) from js console, it brings the editor up in the page

Comment: What is `id = "image";`? Is that the ID of an image, or src, or maybe the actual image data?

Comment: I added a progress bar to help identify when things are fired. It is removed just before launchEditor normally runs. I modified your code to call the launchEditor instead of redefining it, and I added the code to hide the progress bar and the progress bar never goes away

Comment: id = "image", "image" is the div id. This is exactly how the Aviary documentation wants the ID given. They don't want the # included for div ids. Here is the div: <img id="image" style="display:none;" src="/uploads/{{ image_filename }}"/>

Comment: My answer depends on the id in `$(id)` is the actual image, so that it can check if it's loaded. If it's a div then it probably won't work. It needs to be something like `$('#imageID')` by image ID or `$('img')` by the `<img>` tag.

Comment: Oops, it is an <img> tag, I'm sorry. ID is the id of the image tag. I did try using $('#image') as well in your code, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Updated my answer. `.attr('src')` should of course be `.attr('id')`. Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/rthnz/1/. Also, I don't know if Aviary wants the ID in the #image or image format (With or without #).

Comment: It seems to be loading here http://jsfiddle.net/rthnz/1/, even though it wont work because I don't have an api key.

Comment: In your fiddle, I'm not seeing the editor pop up (or an error about it missing an api key) at all. It is erring for you?